# redis dump.rdb / saving small files

Tags: redis

### Context

- I'm using redis. The database is < 100 MB.
- However, I want to make daily backups.
- I'm also running on Ubuntu Server 12.04

When type in:

> **redis-cli** save

I don't know where dump.rdb is saved to (since redis is started as a service and not in my local directory).

### Questions:

1. How do I find where redis is saving my dump.rdb to?
2. Is there someway that I can specify a filename to 'save', so I type in something like:

   > **redis-cli** save ~/db-2012-06-24.rdb

Thanks

Comment: If you can find your config file, the filename is stored with key `dbfilename` and it should be stored relative to the working directory which is found with key `dir`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the file location on the redis.conf file (which you start the server with)
look at the server configuration for that:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb
```

finding the location of the currently saved file, it depends on how you start the server - where you have the redis-server file - i think you can find it with `ps -e aux | grep redis` or `ps -e | grep redis`

Comment: You can actually not sete the file location in this parameter. You need to search for `dir /var/lib/redis` in the config file as @Christoffer pointed out. But yes, filename is this param.

Answer (score 37):

To be a little more helpfull... How to find or set where redis is saving the dump.rdb file (ubuntu server):
First find you redis.conf file: In your terminal run:

```
ps -e aux | grep redis
```

I found my redis.conf file in:

```
var/etc/redis/
```

If yours is the same place then open the file with:

```
pico var/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Look for:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# Also the Append Only File will be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /var/lib/redis
```

Depending on your setting for "dbfilename" and "dir" then that is where you find your redis dump.rdb file.

---

**Update**:
To see your redis configurations just run:

```
redis-cli CONFIG GET *
```

Comment: // , `redis -cli CONFIG GET *` only shows the filename, `dump.rdb`, not the folder it's in. You should see a value for `dir` in `redis -cli CONFIG GET *`. Don't be a 'clever' bloke and set `dir` to `./` in the `redis.conf`.

Comment: A handy shortcut: `cat /usr/local/etc/redis.conf | grep "^dir "`

Answer (score 15):

On my (default, Ubuntu) setup the db file is in

```
/var/lib/redis/redis.rdb
```

As Christoffer points out, you can see all the settings from the command-line client with

```
CONFIG GET *
```

Comment: Do you know the default location for the db file on CEntOS?

Comment: On Ubuntu v18.04, Redis saves to `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` by default.

Answer (score 15):

One liner to get both directory and dump file name

```
echo "CONFIG GET *" | redis-cli | grep -e "dir" -e "dbfilename" -A1
```

Answer (score 3):

In mac,

the location of dump.rdb is at `/usr/local/etc/dump.rdb`.
the location of redis.conf is at `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`.

In order to find the location use the command `find` - `sudo find / -name "redis.conf"`