# Can't find dump.rdb of redis

Tags: redis

I use the command

```
sudo locate *rdb
```

and I can see the following files

- /snap/core/3440/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xrdb
- /snap/core/3604/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xrdb
- /snap/core/3748/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xrdb
- /usr/bin/xrdb /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/services.rdb
- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types.rdb
- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/services/pyuno.rdb
- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/services/services.rdb
- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/offapi.rdb
- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/oovbaapi.rdb
- /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xrdb
- /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb

But I don't have the dump.rdb file. Redis version is 4.0.1

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180999/redis-dump-rdb-saving-small-files

Comment: That helped. Found it in /var/lib/redis. I wonder why it wasn't returned in the locate command.

Comment: Have you run `updatedb`?